# Updating Old Wordpress Permalinks on Nginx

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to change my website over from the default /year/month/day/post_title permalinks, to a simple /post_title/ link, however, when changing it, all of my older links are broken. I've read a site on how to do it on Apache with .htaccess, but need some help on figuring out how to make it work with nginx's location instead of mod_rewrite. 
This is the site that details how to do it on Apache http://www.rickbeckman.org/how-to-update-your-wordpress-permalinks-without-causing-link-rot/

And I tried using this htaccess to nginx converter http://winginx.com/htaccess however, the regex is probably causing a problem and I get this error when  starting nginx

```
    [emerg]: unknown directive "4}/[0-9]" in /usr/local/nginx/sites-enabled/website.com:19
```

And this is my configuration file

```
    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  website.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.website.com/$1 permanent;
   }

    server {
        listen   80;
        server_name www.website.com;
        error_log /home/user/public_html/website.com/log/error.log;
        client_max_body_size 10M;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        location /  {
                    root   /home/user/public_html/website.com/public/;
                    index  index.php index.html;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
                    }
        location ~ ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) {
                    rewrite ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 permanent;
                    }
        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$
                            {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/user/public_html/website.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
                            }
  }
```

Would anyone know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I have also tried to add
        rewrite ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) http://www.website.com/$1 permanent;
In the location / {} however that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding quotes around the regex.

```
    rewrite "^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+)" http://www.website.com/$1;
```

Answer (score 0):

the fix is easy:

```
location ~ ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

the problem with the above is that the rewrite resets the backreferences so the $1 now matches the entire url from your rewrite match, not the $1 from the location match.
the following should work:

```
location ~ ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/([a-z0-9\-/]+) {
  set $post_title $1;
  rewrite ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$post_title permanent;
}
```

(alternatively match the regex in the rewrite rule again)